# Laravel 8.53 - Routing doesnt work on any of pages

Tags: php, laravel

**Solution**

The solution was found thanks to **@Gert B.**

Simply add to your Laravel application any virtual host (I added for mine)
laravel1.test

How to add Virtual host:
Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

add line:

`127.0.0.1           laravel1.test (or your virtual host name)`

And add this to your vhosts(in case of using xampp) in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra httpd-vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.laravel1.test
        ServerAlias laravel1.test
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\public"
        
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\public">
            # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
           RewriteEngine on
            # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php

            # use index.php as index file
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            # ...other settings...
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
           
            ## Apache 2.2
            # Order allow,deny
            # Allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

---

I can't pass the problem with routing in Laravel 8.5 framework. I know there have been many requests about this problem so far but any of given solutions didnt help in my case. I will show Frontend code, since backend is the same thing and also doesnt work. Right now, the only thing that works is index.php.

I know thanks to newest Laravel all bugs are hidden under simple error 404.

[Bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kju4I.png)

I already tried:

- Changing in apache/conf/httpd solution AllowOverride All
- Clearing whole cache and routes cache
- Any possible misspells in code

Still, without any working anwser.

My FrontendController at app/Http/Controllers

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('frontend.index');
    }

    public function object()
    {
        return view('frontend.object');
    }

    public function article()
    {
        return view('frontend.article');
    }


    public function person()
    {
        return view('frontend.person');
    }

    public function room()
    {
        return view('frontend.room');
    }

    public function roomSearch()
    {
        return view('frontend.roomsearch');
    }

}
```

My web.php at app/routes

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController;


##Frontend routes

Route::get('/','FrontendController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/object','FrontendController@object')->name('object');
Route::get('/article','FrontendController@article')->name('article');
Route::get('/person','FrontendController@person')->name('person');
Route::get('/room','FrontendController@room')->name('room');
Route::get('/roomSearch','FrontendController@roomsearch')->name('roomSearch');


##Backend routes
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){

    Route::get('/','BackendController@index')->name('adminHome');

    Route::get('/cities','BackendController@cities')->name('cities');
    Route::get('/myObjects','BackendController@myobjects')->name('myObjects');
    Route::get('/profile','BackendController@profile')->name('profile');
    Route::get('/saveObject','BackendController@saveobject')->name('saveObject');
    Route::get('/saveRoom','BackendController@saveroom')->name('saveRoom');

});
```

.htacces file in app/public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On


   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My routes
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyYZe.png)

Comment: Your domain should point to the laravel public folder. now the route fails because `/laravel1/public` is in the url. Most of the time a local domain is created per project

Comment: @GertB. Thank you for the anwser, what might be good solution for this tho? Should I change something in htacces?

Comment: That depends on the local machine you use. You can add a virtual host for the domain (like localhost ), you can use the serve from laravel, i use Valet for my dev env...

Comment: Omfg. It actually worked. I just had to add virtual host and it worked... I cant believe it. Thank you kindly Sir for your time and solution!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The solution was found thanks to **@Gert B.**

Simply add to your Laravel application any virtual host (I added for mine) laravel1.test

How to add Virtual host: Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

add line:

`127.0.0.1           laravel1.test (or your virtual host name)`

And add this to your vhosts(in case of using xampp) in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra httpd-vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.laravel1.test
        ServerAlias laravel1.test
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\public"
        
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\public">
            # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
           RewriteEngine on
            # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php

            # use index.php as index file
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            # ...other settings...
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
           
            ## Apache 2.2
            # Order allow,deny
            # Allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```